# How can I avoid seeing the loading delay from datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When loading datatables, there is a split second where you can see the plain table (which looks large and generic), then it turns into a smaller, better styled table with all the bells and whistles datatables provides. How can I avoid the user seeing this ugly split second transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Datatables wraps your table element inside a `div.dataTables_wrapper`. Capitalize on that:

```css
table { display: none; }
.dataTables_wrapper table { display: table; }
```